# Ionic unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework

When I suppose to test a method, I got the error like

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_getPortal' of undefined

And my method here

```
onAddRole() {
    this.roleService.getAllRoles() // Here i m getting the error.
      .take(1)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // stuffs
        },
        err => {
          // stuffs
        }
      );
  }
```

Can I get any help on this?

Comment: so uhmm, is this the unit test or ....? And what's happening in `getAllRoles()`?

Comment: This is the main method. This is used to backend API call. For this, I need to write unit test case.